# Factoring $x^{2}-y^{2}$ as a product of two expressions such that neither expression is a constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question asks me to write  $x^{2}-y^{2}$ as a product of two expressions such that neither expression is a constant.

Why is the "neither expression is a constant" clause important?

How do i factorise the two expressions above? The only thing i can think of is $x \cdot x - y \cdot y$.

Comment: They mean something like $2 \cdot (\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y^2))$ doesn't count as a valid (interesting) factorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$

Comment: Ah, this seems less immediately intuitive than what I've encountered before. Is there similar ones to this out there?